# Adding multiple variables to lists within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator, append

i would like to ask about how i could add multiple variables to a list within a list in  python.

```
yearmonthlst = [[] for i in range(64)]
precipitation = [197.6, 95.0, 37.1, 74.2, 65.3, 175.5, 114.6, 90.4, 26.7, 62.2, 58.9, 142.0, 129.0, 122.2...]
```

So for example here i have a list that has 64 other lists inside in it. Then i have another list with a lot of values. For every value until the 13th in precipitation it will get appended to a list within yearmonthlst

```
[197.6, 95.0, 37.1, 74.2, 65.3, 175.5, 114.6, 90.4, 26.7, 62.2, 58.9, 142.0], ['''12 values within this list'''], ['''12 values within this list''']...]
```

I would like to have 12 values from precipitation in every list within the yearmonthlst. So it starts from precipitation[0] up to [11] those will get appended to yearmonthlst[0], then iterates over another list yearmonthlst[1], continuing from the values that have been iterated in precipitation,
so values [12] - [23] get appended to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[precipitation[i:i+12] for i  in range(0, len(precipitation), 12)]
```

input :

```
precipitation = [197.6, 95.0, 37.1, 74.2, 65.3, 175.5, 114.6, 90.4, 26.7, 62.2, 58.9, 142.0, 129.0, 122.2]
```

output :

```
[[197.6, 95.0, 37.1, 74.2, 65.3, 175.5, 114.6, 90.4, 26.7, 62.2, 58.9, 142.0], [129.0, 122.2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for index, value in enumerate(precipitation):
    yearmonthlst[index % 12].append(value)
```